# IIFE version lightningchart xydata

Tags: lightningchart

const {
createSampledDataGenerator
} = require('@arction/xydata')

Hi all, I'm trying to let this ECG (https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0150-ecg.html) work without nodejs or nmp. I've seen that is possible to use IIFE js version. Implementing the IIFE version on the website i find an error running the above command, I'm not able to execute in in my webserver. How can i run it? Is there an IIFE version of xydata?
What script do i have to include and how? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xydata` can be run directly in browser by using the `.iife.js` version of the xydata build. You can either download the `@arction/xydata` package from npm and use the `xydata.iife.js` file from there or alternatively you can use a CDN like [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com/).

In your html head add `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/xydata@1.2.1/dist/xydata.iife.js">` (replace src url if you are providing the file locally)
And then replace the `require("@arction/xydata")` with just `xydata`. The iife file will add the `xydata` variable to the global context.

See a full working example below. I did have to cut the amount of data in the example to be able to fit the example here, as StackOverflow limits the length of an answer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@2.0.3/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/xydata@1.2.1/dist/xydata.iife.js"></script>
  <title>Using chart in HTML page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Flexbox styling to have the chart and header fill the page.
        Chart will take as much space as possible. -->
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .box {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: column;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .box .row.header {
      flex: 0 1 auto;
    }
    
    .box .row.content {
      flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="box">
  <h1 class="row header">LightningChart<sup>&#174;</sup> JS in HTML page</h1>

  <!-- Create div to render the chart into-->
  <div id="target" class="row content"></div>

  <!--IIFE assembly (lcjs.iife.js) is a standalone JS file, 
      which does not need any build tools, 
      such as NPM, to be installed-->
  <!--Script source must be defined in it's own script tag-->
  <script src="lcjs.iife.js"></script>

  <!--Actual chart related script tag-->
  <script>
    // Replace the contents of this script tag if you want to test code from our examples:
    // https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/

    // Extract required parts from LightningChartJS.
    const {
      lightningChart,
      DataPatterns,
      AxisScrollStrategies,
      SolidLine,
      SolidFill,
      ColorHEX,
      AutoCursorModes,
      Themes
    } = lcjs

    // Import data-generators from 'xydata'-library.
    const {
      createSampledDataGenerator
    } = xydata

    // Create a XY Chart.
    const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
      // theme: Themes.dark
      container: 'target'
    }).setTitle('ECG')

    // Add line series to visualize the data received
    const series = chart.addLineSeries({
      dataPattern: DataPatterns.horizontalProgressive
    })
    // Style the series
    series
      .setStrokeStyle(new SolidLine({
        thickness: 2,
        fillStyle: new SolidFill({
          color: ColorHEX('#5aafc7')
        })
      }))
      .setMouseInteractions(false)

    chart.setAutoCursorMode(AutoCursorModes.disabled)

    // Setup view nicely.
    chart.getDefaultAxisY()
      .setTitle('mV')
      .setInterval(-1600, 1000)
      .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.expansion)

    chart.getDefaultAxisX()
      .setTitle('milliseconds')
      .setInterval(0, 2500)
      .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive)

    // Points that are used to generate a continuous stream of data.
    const point = [{
        x: 2,
        y: 81
      },
      {
        x: 3,
        y: 83
      },
      {
        x: 4,
        y: 88
      },
      {
        x: 5,
        y: 98
      },
      {
        x: 6,
        y: 92
      },
      {
        x: 7,
        y: 85
      },
      {
        x: 8,
        y: 73
      },
      {
        x: 9,
        y: 71
      },
      {
        x: 10,
        y: 70
      },
      {
        x: 11,
        y: 83
      },
      {
        x: 12,
        y: 73
      },
      {
        x: 13,
        y: 79
      },
      {
        x: 14,
        y: 84
      },
      {
        x: 15,
        y: 78
      },
      {
        x: 16,
        y: 67
      },
      {
        x: 17,
        y: 71
      },
      {
        x: 18,
        y: 76
      },
      {
        x: 19,
        y: 77
      },
      {
        x: 20,
        y: 64
      },
      {
        x: 21,
        y: 53
      },
      {
        x: 22,
        y: 0
      },
      {
        x: 23,
        y: 41
      },
      {
        x: 24,
        y: 51
      },
      {
        x: 25,
        y: 3
      },
      {
        x: 26,
        y: 31
      },
      {
        x: 27,
        y: 37
      },
      {
        x: 28,
        y: 35
      },
      {
        x: 29,
        y: 48
      },
      {
        x: 30,
        y: 40
      },
      {
        x: 31,
        y: 42
      },
      {
        x: 32,
        y: 42
      },
      {
        x: 33,
        y: 32
      },
      {
        x: 34,
        y: 21
      },
      {
        x: 35,
        y: 41
      },
      {
        x: 36,
        y: 48
      },
      {
        x: 37,
        y: 47
      },
      {
        x: 38,
        y: 45
      },
      {
        x: 39,
        y: 42
      },
      {
        x: 40,
        y: 28
      },
      {
        x: 41,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 42,
        y: 1
      },
      {
        x: 43,
        y: -12
      },
      {
        x: 44,
        y: -4
      },
      {
        x: 45,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 46,
        y: 23
      },
      {
        x: 47,
        y: 22
      },
      {
        x: 48,
        y: 40
      },
      {
        x: 49,
        y: 46
      },
      {
        x: 50,
        y: 49
      },
      {
        x: 51,
        y: 48
      },
      {
        x: 52,
        y: 43
      },
      {
        x: 53,
        y: 52
      },
      {
        x: 54,
        y: 49
      },
      {
        x: 55,
        y: 44
      },
      {
        x: 56,
        y: 41
      },
      {
        x: 57,
        y: 41
      },
      {
        x: 58,
        y: 45
      },
      {
        x: 59,
        y: 57
      },
      {
        x: 60,
        y: 67
      },
      {
        x: 61,
        y: 65
      },
      {
        x: 62,
        y: 58
      },
      {
        x: 63,
        y: 47
      },
      {
        x: 64,
        y: 34
      },
      {
        x: 65,
        y: 35
      },
      {
        x: 66,
        y: 23
      },
      {
        x: 67,
        y: 11
      },
      {
        x: 68,
        y: 7
      },
      {
        x: 69,
        y: 14
      },
      {
        x: 70,
        y: 23
      },
      {
        x: 71,
        y: 18
      },
      {
        x: 72,
        y: 31
      },
      {
        x: 73,
        y: 35
      },
      {
        x: 74,
        y: 44
      },
      {
        x: 75,
        y: 49
      },
      {
        x: 76,
        y: 34
      },
      {
        x: 77,
        y: 7
      },
      {
        x: 78,
        y: -3
      },
      {
        x: 79,
        y: -8
      },
      {
        x: 80,
        y: -11
      },
      {
        x: 81,
        y: -20
      },
      {
        x: 82,
        y: -28
      },
      {
        x: 83,
        y: -4
      },
      {
        x: 84,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 85,
        y: 20
      },
      {
        x: 86,
        y: 26
      },
      {
        x: 87,
        y: 26
      },
      {
        x: 88,
        y: 24
      },
      {
        x: 89,
        y: 34
      },
      {
        x: 90,
        y: 35
      },
      {
        x: 91,
        y: 30
      },
      {
        x: 92,
        y: 22
      },
      {
        x: 93,
        y: 12
      },
      {
        x: 94,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 95,
        y: 18
      },
      {
        x: 96,
        y: 24
      },
      {
        x: 97,
        y: 18
      },
      {
        x: 98,
        y: 26
      },
      {
        x: 99,
        y: 25
      },
      {
        x: 100,
        y: 13
      },
      {
        x: 101,
        y: 2
      },
      {
        x: 102,
        y: 1
      },
      {
        x: 103,
        y: -10
      },
      {
        x: 104,
        y: -10
      },
      {
        x: 105,
        y: -4
      },
      {
        x: 106,
        y: 8
      },
      {
        x: 107,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 108,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 109,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 110,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 111,
        y: 18
      },
      {
        x: 112,
        y: 19
      },
      {
        x: 113,
        y: 3
      },
      {
        x: 114,
        y: -12
      },
      {
        x: 115,
        y: -14
      },
      {
        x: 116,
        y: -10
      },
      {
        x: 117,
        y: -22
      },
      {
        x: 118,
        y: -24
      },
      {
        x: 119,
        y: -29
      },
      {
        x: 120,
        y: -21
      },
      {
        x: 121,
        y: -19
      },
      {
        x: 122,
        y: -26
      },
      {
        x: 123,
        y: -9
      },
      {
        x: 124,
        y: -10
      },
      {
        x: 125,
        y: -6
      },
      {
        x: 126,
        y: -8
      },
      {
        x: 127,
        y: -31
      },
      {
        x: 128,
        y: -52
      },
      {
        x: 129,
        y: -57
      },
      {
        x: 130,
        y: -40
      },
      {
        x: 131,
        y: -20
      },
      {
        x: 132,
        y: 7
      },
      {
        x: 133,
        y: 14
      },
      {
        x: 134,
        y: 10
      },
      {
        x: 135,
        y: 6
      },
      {
        x: 136,
        y: 12
      },
      {
        x: 137,
        y: -5
      },
      {
        x: 138,
        y: -2
      },
      {
        x: 139,
        y: 9
      },
      {
        x: 140,
        y: 23
      },
      {
        x: 141,
        y: 36
      },
      {
        x: 142,
        y: 52
      },
      {
        x: 143,
        y: 61
      },
      {
        x: 144,
        y: 56
      },
      {
        x: 145,
        y: 48
      },
      {
        x: 146,
        y: 48
      },
      {
        x: 147,
        y: 38
      },
      {
        x: 148,
        y: 29
      },
      {
        x: 149,
        y: 33
      },
      {
        x: 150,
        y: 20
      },
      {
        x: 151,
        y: 1
      },
      {
        x: 152,
        y: -7
      },
      {
        x: 153,
        y: -9
      },
      {
        x: 154,
        y: -4
      },
      {
        x: 155,
        y: -12
      },
      {
        x: 156,
        y: -3
      },
      {
        x: 157,
        y: 5
      },
      {
        x: 158,
        y: -3
      },
      {
        x: 159,
        y: 12
      },
      {
        x: 160,
        y: 6
      },
      {
        x: 161,
        y: -10
      },
      {
        x: 162,
        y: -2
      },
      {
        x: 163,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 164,
        y: 17
      },
      {
        x: 165,
        y: 21
      },
      {
        x: 166,
        y: 22
      },
      {
        x: 167,
        y: 15
      },
      {
        x: 168,
        y: 16
      },
      {
        x: 169,
        y: 1
      },
      {
        x: 170,
        y: -2
      },
      {
        x: 171,
        y: -9
      },
      {
        x: 172,
        y: -16
      },
      {
        x: 173,
        y: -18
      }
    ]
    // Create a data generator to supply a continuous stream of data.
    createSampledDataGenerator(point, 1, 10)
      .setSamplingFrequency(1)
      .setInputData(point)
      .generate()
      .setStreamBatchSize(48)
      .setStreamInterval(50)
      .setStreamRepeat(true)
      .toStream()
      .forEach(point => {
        // Push the created points to the series.
        series.add({
          x: point.timestamp,
          y: point.data.y
        })
      })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```